# Use data from NSUserDefaults in UIPickerView - pickerView stays empty

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

I tried to set up NSUserDefaults last night but an error keeps occurring:

**ViewController3:**

*save data*

```
  @IBAction func tappedAddButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var exercisesList:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("exercisesList") as? NSMutableArray

    var dataSet:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dataSet.setObject(textField.text, forKey: "exercises")

    if ((exercisesList) != nil){
        var newMutableList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();

        for dict:AnyObject in exercisesList!{
            newMutableList.addObject(dict as NSDictionary)
        }

        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("exercisesList")
        newMutableList.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(newMutableList, forKey: "exercisesList")

    }else{
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("exercisesList")
        exercisesList = NSMutableArray()
        exercisesList!.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(exercisesList, forKey: "exercisesList")
    }

    userDefaults.synchronize()

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    textField.text = ""

}
```

**ViewController1:**

*load data*

```
 var exercises:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
```

...

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var exercisesListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("exercisesList") as? NSMutableArray

    if ((exercisesListFromUserDefaults) != nil){
        exercises = exercisesListFromUserDefaults!
    }

}
```

**While adding some data to the variable "exercises", the pickerView stays empty.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting userDefaults with the key "exercisesList" but attempting to get the data back with a different key ("itemList")

Comment: Thanks but my App is now crashing every time I start a test run

Comment: @santa1 - I guess my answer was correct answer for your original question. Now you have changed the question (twice)... its going to be a thankless task keeping up with you. As to why the pickerView is empty, you would need to show the pickerView dataSource and delegate methods. Perhaps you should mark this answer as correct and open a new question showing all the relevant code.

Comment: @santa1 - thanks for the tick - I may have solved part 2 of your problem in your other question. On to part 3!

Comment: What do you mean by part 3?

Comment: @santa1, sorry i was being unduly pessimistic, once you have part 2 solved, you may still find you have issues with NSUserDefaults (which was the drift of your original question).

Comment: Ah ok. Yes I still have issues but maybe you have any idea on how to solve them.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175743/uipickerview-wont-display-the-data-loaded-from-nsuserdefaults-app-is-crashing